Expected frequency of a letter in a sampled word with replacements
Consider the setting where we have the following:

An alphabet of $M$ letters.
Each letter $j$ in this alphabet has a probability $p_j$ of being sampled, and $\sum p_j = 1$.

We sample letters with replacement until we have a "word" consisting of $N$ unique letters.
I am interested in the expected frequency of the letter $j$ in the sampled "word".
This is somewhat related to the coupon collector's problem with non-uniform probabilities and partial collection. However, there, the focus is on the expected total number of letters in the word and not the frequency of each letter. In corollary 4.2 in Flajolet et al, the authors derive the expectation for the total number of letters.
So my question is,

Is it possible to derive a similar formula for the expected frequencies of the letters?
Could the computations be simplified if a subset of the letters have the same sampling probability?

Below, I have written a code that empirically estimates the sampling frequencies.
# The alphabet of possible letter
alphabet = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")

# The probabilities of sampling each letter
prob = c(0.3, 0.175, 0.15, 0.125, 0.1, 0.065, 0.04, 0.025, 0.015, 0.005)

# Number of repetitions
B = 50000

# 3D array to store the results 
freq = array(NA, dim = c(length(alphabet), B, length(alphabet)))

# Iterate over the word lengths and the repetitions
for (word_length in seq(length(alphabet))) {
  print(word_length)
  for (b in seq(B)) {
    
    # Number of unique letters in the sampled "word"
    unique = 0
    word = c()
    
    # Sample new letters until the number of unique letters in the word equals the word_length
    while (unique < word_length) {
      new_letters = sample(x = alphabet, size = word_length - unique, replace = TRUE, prob = prob)
      word = c(word, new_letters)
      unique = length(unique(word))
    }
    
    # Compute the frequencies of each letter in the word
    freq[word_length, b, ] = sapply(alphabet, function(letter) mean(word == letter))
  }
}

# Compute the mean over the repetitions for each word length
expected_freq = sapply(seq(length(alphabet)), function(word_length) apply(freq[word_length,,], 2, mean))

# Plot the results
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(expected_freq)
setnames(dt, paste(seq(length(alphabet))))
dt[, `:=` (letter = alphabet) ]
dt = melt(dt, id = "letter", variable.name = "word_length_unique", value.name = "expected_frequence")
ggplot(data = dt, aes(x = word_length_unique, y = expected_frequence, group = letter, col = letter)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Unique letters in word", y = "Expected frequency of letter in word", col = "Letter")

My figure of the simulated letter frequencies:


!["https://i.sstatic.net/6FvYk9BM.png"](Figure of the simulated letter frequencies)

I doubt this is easy if you are finding the frequency in each possible word and then finding the expectation of this across possible words (weighted by their probability).  Some words will be longer than others. So for example with $N=2$, the expected length of words seems to be about $2.228211$ and the expected number of times a appears in them is $0.668463$ for a ratio of $0.3$, but the average of the frequency a within words is $0.2823317$, similar to your simulation  ($0$ with probability $0.460107$, $\frac12$ with prob $0.42$, $\frac23$ prob $0.063$, $\frac13$ prob $0.025635$, etc.).
